# WSO2 Enterprise mobility manager: unable to send email invite from localhost

Tags: email, smtp, wso2, mdm, wso2-iot

Hi i am working on wso2 Enterprise mobility manager, i followed all the steps mentioned [here](https://docs.wso2.org/display/EMM101/General+Server+Configurations)

But i am facing issues with inviting the user , i made email configuration in all **congif.json** file as below

```
"email": {

        "smtp":'smtp.gmail.com',
        "port":'465',
        "companyName": 'Mobilefirst',
        "senderAddress": 'myemail@gmail.com',
        "emailPassword": 'mobility'
    },
```

also i cannot even remove the user , iam working this on the **localhost**, can some one point me in right direction.Is it possible to send invite from local host? on it should be in production?Any help is appreciated.

tried with **ssl:smtp gmail com** and **tsl:smtp gmail com**  giving unknownhostexception smtp gmail com

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use smtp address as smtp.gmail.com and port number as 25. This should resolve your problem. No need to use the ssl:// prefix.